# Delphi XE7 marks as unknown some sourse files in uses - clause

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am trying to migrate from Delphi XE to Delphi XE7, so I opened my Delphi XE - project, but it can not be compiled, because Delphi XE7 does not recognize from clause:
  uses
    IBDatabase, IBCustomDataSet, IBQuery, IBStoredProc.
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you install the IBO components into XE7 first?

Comment: I did not install any components, because, I don't know how .... Under Delphi XE these components were installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi XE7 does accept as known from clause: 
uses
  IBX.IBDatabase, IBX.IBCustomDataSet, IBX.IBQuery, IBX.IBStoredProc.
The project with these declarations was compiled successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

In broad terms this is down to the introduction of unit scope names. The change was made in XE2 to facilitate FireMonkey. The documentation that you need to read can be found here: [Unit Scope Names (XE2 documentation)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Unit_Scope_Names).

However, note that the table of unit scope names listed there does not include IBX. In fact the unit scope name change that impacts the IBX units was made in XE6: [Unit Scope Names (XE6 documentation)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Unit_Scope_Names). The list of unit scope names for this version of the documentation lists IBX. All of your units now require an `IBX` unit scope name.

Note that you could add `IBX` to the [unit scope names project option](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler) to simplify migration.